# How i can to make a new public rest api with apex classes

Tags: salesforce

How i can to  make a new public rest api with apex classes, to return JSON from salesforce.

i make apex classes, but i can't know how to make url ( i see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-nzywBLUbM ) but this old and not all steps found ).

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myService')
global class MyService {
    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the Web Service via a Force.com Site and then ensure that the Site User's profile has access to the Apex Class. [Exposing Apex Rest Web Services](http://www.mkpartners.com/support/Exposing-Apex-REST-Web-Servies-via-Force-com-Sites)